# Nan values in csv covert to null values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, null, nan

Hi I am currently converting a table with some NULL values from MS SQL database to csv which means all these NULL values will become NaN. Then I plan to convert the csv to MySQL database, however, they give me an error saying unknown column 'nan' in field list. Does anyone know how to solve this? (I tried some methods but it still didnt work) Thank you!

This is my MS sql table:

`Header: [Testtag, Date, Temperature, Humidity, Zone1_Voltage, Zone1_Current, Zone1B_Voltage, Zone1B_Current, Zone1C_Voltage, Zone1C_Current, Zone2_Voltage, Zone2_Current, Zone2B_Voltage, Zone2B_Current, Zone2C_Voltage, Zone2C_Current, Zone3_Voltage, Zone3_Current, Zone3B_Voltage, Zone3B_Current, Zone3C_Voltage, Zone3C_Current, Zone4_Voltage, Zone4_Current, Zone4B_Voltage, Zone4B_Current, Zone4C_Voltage, Zone4C_Current, Zone5_Voltage, Zone5_Current, Zone5B_Voltage, Zone5B_Current, Zone5C_Voltage, Zone5C_Current, Zone6_Voltage, Zone6_Current, Zone6B_Voltage, Zone6B_Current, Zone6C_Voltage, Zone6C_Current] Data:[151, NULL, NULL, NULL,..., NULL, NULL]`

This is my csv table (copy paste to txt file so easier to see):

Testtag,    Date,   TEMPERATURE,    HUMIDITY,   Zone1_Voltage,  Zone1_Current,  Zone1B_Voltage, Zone1B_Current, Zone1C_Voltage, Zone1C_Current, Zone2_Voltage,  Zone2_Current,  Zone2B_Voltage, Zone2B_Current, Zone2C_Voltage, Zone2C_Current, Zone3_Voltage   Zone3_Current,  Zone3B_Voltage, Zone3B_Current, Zone3C_Voltage, Zone3C_Current, Zone4_Voltage,  Zone4_Current,  Zone4B_Voltage, Zone4B_Current, Zone4C_Voltage, Zone4C_Current, Zone5_Voltage,  Zone5_Current,  Zone5B_Voltage, Zone5B_Current, Zone5C_Voltage, Zone5C_Current, Zone6_Voltage,  Zone6_Current,  Zone6B_Voltage, Zone6B_Current, Zone6C_Voltage, Zone6C_Current
[Data starts here, each row of data is indicated by 'SG' string until the next 'SG' string]
SG_QRA_SGBAKE_0012, 54:01.1,    151,    ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,
SG_QRA_SGBAKE_0013, 54:01.1,    125,    ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,
SG_QRA_SGHAST_0005, 54:01.1,    84.72,  12.05,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,
SG_QRA_SGHAST_0006, 54:01.1,    57.88,  35.25,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,
SG_QRA_SGHAST_0007, 54:01.1,    110,    85.03,  3.6,    0,  0,  0,  1.3,    0.24,   3.6,    0,  0,  0,  1.3,    0.24,   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,   ,

My query is this:

`CREATE TABLE skynet_msa.chamber_data (Testtag varchar(255), Date datetime, Temperature varchar(255), Humidity varchar(255), Zone1_Voltage varchar(255), Zone1_Current varchar(255), Zone1B_Voltage varchar(255), Zone1B_Current varchar(255), Zone1C_Voltage varchar(255), Zone1C_Current varchar(255), Zone2_Voltage varchar(255), Zone2_Current varchar(255), Zone2B_Voltage varchar(255), Zone2B_Current varchar(255), Zone2C_Voltage varchar(255), Zone2C_Current varchar(255), Zone3_Voltage varchar(255), Zone3_Current varchar(255), Zone3B_Voltage varchar(255), Zone3B_Current varchar(255), Zone3C_Voltage varchar(255), Zone3C_Current varchar(255), Zone4_Voltage varchar(255), Zone4_Current varchar(255), Zone4B_Voltage varchar(255), Zone4B_Current varchar(255), Zone4C_Voltage varchar(255), Zone4C_Current varchar(255), Zone5_Voltage varchar(255), Zone5_Current varchar(255), Zone5B_Voltage varchar(255), Zone5B_Current varchar(255), Zone5C_Voltage varchar(255), Zone5C_Current varchar(255), Zone6_Voltage varchar(255), Zone6_Current varchar(255), Zone6B_Voltage varchar(255), Zone6B_Current varchar(255), Zone6C_Voltage varchar(255), Zone6C_Current varchar(255)`

`INSERT INTO skynet_msa.chamber_data (Testtag, Date, Temperature, Humidity, Zone1_Voltage, Zone1_Current, Zone1B_Voltage, Zone1B_Current, Zone1C_Voltage, Zone1C_Current, Zone2_Voltage, Zone2_Current, Zone2B_Voltage, Zone2B_Current, Zone2C_Voltage, Zone2C_Current, Zone3_Voltage, Zone3_Current, Zone3B_Voltage, Zone3B_Current, Zone3C_Voltage, Zone3C_Current, Zone4_Voltage, Zone4_Current, Zone4B_Voltage, Zone4B_Current, Zone4C_Voltage, Zone4C_Current, Zone5_Voltage, Zone5_Current, Zone5B_Voltage, Zone5B_Current, Zone5C_Voltage, Zone5C_Current, Zone6_Voltage, Zone6_Current, Zone6B_Voltage, Zone6B_Current, Zone6C_Voltage, Zone6C_Current) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)`

I used pandas to read csv to df to mysql:

```
for i,row in df4.iterrows():
   
        sql = "INSERT INTO skynet_msa.chamber_data (Testtag, Date, Temperature, Humidity, Zone1_Voltage, Zone1_Current, Zone1B_Voltage, Zone1B_Current, Zone1C_Voltage, Zone1C_Current, Zone2_Voltage, Zone2_Current, Zone2B_Voltage, Zone2B_Current, Zone2C_Voltage, Zone2C_Current, Zone3_Voltage, Zone3_Current, Zone3B_Voltage, Zone3B_Current, Zone3C_Voltage, Zone3C_Current, Zone4_Voltage, Zone4_Current, Zone4B_Voltage, Zone4B_Current, Zone4C_Voltage, Zone4C_Current, Zone5_Voltage, Zone5_Current, Zone5B_Voltage, Zone5B_Current, Zone5C_Voltage, Zone5C_Current, Zone6_Voltage, Zone6_Current, Zone6B_Voltage, Zone6B_Current, Zone6C_Voltage, Zone6C_Current) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
        print("Record inserted")
        # the connection is not auto committed by default, so we must commit to save our changes
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: *I plan to convert the csv to MySQL database, however, they give me an error saying unknown column 'nan' in field list.* Provide a sample of CSV body (3-5 lines), MySQL table which you want to import the data into (CREATE TABLE), and SQL query which you try to use.

Comment: The section headed Input Preprocessing - here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html may be useful

Comment: @Akina just added the type of data in the qn

Comment: Why? You're not interested in?

Comment: it's thousands rows of data so i just put example of the null values in one row of data

Comment: Have you allowed null in mysql db?

Comment: @JoelCryptothe default expression of all columns is null, is tht wht u mean?

Comment: *Provide a sample of CSV body (3-5 lines)* - I do not see it. *MySQL table which you want to import the data into (CREATE TABLE)* - I do not see CREATE TABLE script. *SQL query which you try to use* - I do not see SQL query which imports the data from CSV file into MySQL table (you even do not tell what statement type is used). *My query is this:* This query produces a rowset and not CSV file.

Comment: @Akina hi i just added the ones u asked! sorry i got formatting issue jn so a bit difficult to share here

Comment: the ',' represents delimiter and if there are multiple delimiters shown it is because there are empty values in the csv

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing nan values to empty string using python pandas

```
df1=df.replace(np.nan, '')
```

Comment: Can you please add some code to your answer? That'll help the asker and the community both.